# Using C++11 versus GCC 4.8 default causes link error with private inheritance and boost

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc, abi

## Preamble

Working with a large piece of code that I can't currently break down into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I'll do my best.

---

## Problem

I'm working with a large project that is compiled as a static library, `libfoo.a`. A separate project, `bar`, links against that library. The "offending" snippet in `libfoo` is as follows:

```
class Base {
public:
    void foo(){}
    void bar(){}
};

class Derived : private Base {
public:
    using Base::foo;
};
```

Both `libfoo` and `bar` make extensive use of [boost](/questions/tagged/boost). `bar` has to be compiled with `-std=c++11` due to C++11 features it makes use of, but `libfoo` can be compiled with minimal options (i.e. <s>`-std=c++0x`</s> **the default compiler options used by GCC v4.8**, which appears to be `-std=gnu++03`).

When I attempt to link `bar` using a <s>`-std=c++0x`</s> **GCC defaults** compiled `libfoo.a`, it fails with a lengthy, name-mangled warning, which reduces to:

```
Undefined reference to Base::Derived::foo()
```

When I re-build `libfoo.a` with `-std=c++11`, this issue no longer occurs.

---

## Work So Far

I compared the output of `libfoo.a` via [nm](/questions/tagged/nm) and in both cases, the appropriate symbols were present. I've also gone through [the Cxx11Abi compatibility documents](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility), and it doesn't appear that this compiler setting should "break" compatibility.

---

## Question

What is the **cause** of this linker issue?

Comment: what do you mean with "minimum settings" ? shouldnt `-std=c++11` be the same as `-std=c++0x` ?

Comment: @tobi303 By that, I meant no additional compiler options (i.e. the default settings by the compiler: GCC v4.8.4 in this case).

Comment: the problem might be that environment would yse different headers for draft and for release 2011 standard

Comment: @Swift I updated the question, as per an error of mine @[tobi303](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/tobi303) pointed out.

Comment: Comparing the link command lines might hint of the problem (with `-v`)

Comment: it might be a tricky one... the problem might be in exact symbol (not the substitute foo) matching something in standard library, because due to how using keyword works (c++ 11 standard says its an undefined behaviour to use identifiers defined in standard)

Comment: You say "libfoo *can* be compiled with minimal options" (my emphasis).  The obvious fix is to try compiling it with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Agreed, and that's what I've done to fix this. However, I'm very interested in figuring out the root, low-level cause of the issue, since it "shouldn't" be happening, AFAIK.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is that the type of `foo` is different in a c++11 world than in a gnu++03 world.  (Perhaps an argument of `foo` has moved from namespace `std::experimental` to `std` ?)

Comment: Do you use preprocessor conditionals or other mechanisms to provide different class definitions in C++03 and C++11 mode? How do you export a C++03-compatible interface for the C++11 library?

Comment: I found a solution, but it's not practical to share it. This question can't be edited to help future readers, so I'm voting to close my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MartinBonner notes, it had to do with namespace changes to types that were used in function prototypes. The only solutions were to either compile via `-std=c++11` or re-write massive amounts of code to have an extra layer of "abstraction" around the type.

Comment: Could you give an example of an namespace change?  Doing so would make this a much better answer.